# send data periodically from client to server in Mina

Tags: java, server, client, apache-mina

I want to send data periodically from client to server. How can I do that in Mina while the data will send via client handler.
I write openSocket() function like this:

```
    public void openSocket(Object c)
{
    connector.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new myCodecFactory()));

    connector.setHandler(new net.floodlightcontroller.Example.ClientSessionHandler(c));
    ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT));
    future.awaitUninterruptibly();

    IoSession session = future.getSession();
    session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
    session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

     connector.dispose();   
}
```

as you see the function receive an object which contain my initial data after I call it in init() function. if I want to send another data after a period of second by the same connection, How can I do that. if I call openSocket() function like below code it does not work. where can I call it and How?

```
try {
        while (true){
        openSocket(cObj);
        Thread.sleep(5000, 5);}
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
```